# Simple questions about the scotty Haskell web framework

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-warp, haskell-wai

Consider the simplest scotty app:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

I put this code into `app.hs` and compile it with GHC. I run it with `./app`. Simple.

1. What really happens when people visit the site? It's only one `./app` that's running. Does a new thread get created within this same app whenever each user triggers a `get "/:word" $ do` line? How many such threads can exist? Thousand? Ten thousand?
2. After running `./app` it shows the message `Setting phasers to stun... (port 3000) (ctrl-c to quit)`. But it shows nothing more. It doesn't output the incoming web requests. How can I make it do that? This would be useful for logging purposes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using GHC, each request to the scotty server essentially creates a "green thread" that is scheduled by the GHC runtime. You can easily have thousands of those running at a time.

Scotty itself doesn't do any request logging but since it is built on top of [WAI](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/web-application-interface), you can use any middleware component that exists for it, for example [`RequestLogger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    middleware logStdoutDev

    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. If you know how to answer my next question about a scotty app behind nginx, feel free: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537495/logging-when-scotty-haskell-web-app-is-running-behind-nginx

Comment: what manages those green threads? what decides when and how many create and kill?

Answer (score 11):

> 1. What really happens when people visit the site? It's only one ./app that's running. Does a new thread get created within this same app whenever each user triggers a get "/:word" $ do line? How many such threads can exist? Thousand? Ten thousand?

Scotty is build around [warp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp), but could use any other library that implements the [web application interface (WAI)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai). A new lightweight thread gets created with `forkIOUnmasked` (hidden in [`fork`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.0.1.1/docs/src/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp-Run.html#fork) in the module `Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.Run`). You can have *many* of those:

> Concurrency is "lightweight", which means that both thread creation and context switching overheads are extremely low. Scheduling of Haskell threads is done internally in the Haskell runtime system, and doesn't make use of any operating system-supplied thread packages. [(source)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO)

Here's a [performance comparison between nginx and warp](http://aosabook.org/en/posa/warp.html), which also includes information about the general idea behind warp.

> 2. After running ./app it shows the message Setting phasers to stun... (port 3000) (ctrl-c to quit). But it shows nothing more. It doesn't output the incoming web requests. How can I make it do that? This would be useful for logging purposes.

What's the type of your `do` block? It should be `ScottyM`, since `scotty :: Port -> ScottyM () -> IO ()`. If `ScottyM` is an instance of `MonadIO`, you can use `liftIO` together with `putStrLn` (or any other `IO` action).

Now, [`ScottyM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.0/docs/Web-Scotty.html#t:ScottyM) is actually a type synonym for [`ScottyT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.0/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ScottyT), which is in fact a instance of [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO). Also, the inner monad `ActionM` is also a type synonym for `ActionT`, which is also a `MonadIO`. Therefore, logging is as easy as

```
main = scotty 3000 $ do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "incoming request"
    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        liftIO $ print $ mconcat ["get, word = ", beam]
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

However, keep in mind that logging to a terminal might not be a good idea when you really expect ten thousand requests per second.