# How to log the real IP address when behind a proxy using Scotty / wai

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-warp, haskell-wai

This is my scotty app, notice how I am logging requests to the console:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    --log requests to console
    middleware logStdoutDev

    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

My scotty app runs behind nginx using the proxy mechanism. This causes the scotty app to log like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2014:15:12:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 - ...
```

I want the **REAL IP ADDRESS** to be logged.

I had the same issue in my Node.js/Express apps, where I solved it like this:

[Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)

How do I solve this problem in Scotty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an `IPAddrSource` data type in [`wai-extra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html) which originates in the [`wai-logger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-logger-2.2.3/docs/Network-Wai-Logger.html) package. So, if you want the IP address to come from a header, it looks like you can do something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Data.Default

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    --log requests to console
    logger <- liftIO $ mkRequestLogger def { outputFormat = Apache FromHeader }
    middleware logger

    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

From the description, it also looks like `Apache FromFallback` will check the headers first, and use the socket IP address if no header is found.

### Update

You can also just create the logger outside the `scotty` function:

```
main = do
    logger <- mkRequestLogger def { outputFormat = Apache FromHeader }
    scotty 3000 $ do
        middleware logger

        get "/:word" $ do
            beam <- param "word"
            html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

Comment: Hi Luke. Your code worked perfectly back in 2014. But now, with the latest Stack snapshot, it no longer compiles. (It's complaining now that there is no `MonadIO` instance for the stuff that `mkRequestLogger` returns.) Do you have time to look at what changed in the meantime and how to get around it? I'd be happy to give you +50 bounty award for it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I've set the bounty and can award it to you in 24 hours. Another question in the meantime: Can you see why things stopped working? Did they just remove a `MonadIO` instance at some point? As an experienced Haskell programmer, can you imagine why they would do that in the first place?

Comment: If you look at the changelog, you can see that the `MonadIO` instance [was removed from `ActionT`](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/commit/7e2960245c798a2eb7b9d58e270c11cbf7edb877). The commit log doesn't explain the motivation though, but I guess it allows for situations where you don't want all IO exceptions to be trapped within Scotty, which is what happened before.

Comment: Looks like it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/issues/175).

Comment: Thanks! You'll get the bounty in 6 hours :)